# Predicate and fast aggregation in hazelcast

Tags: aggregation, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a requirement when I want to  aggregate on a part of the Imap rather than whole map.
But i did not see any documentation around using predicate in fast aggregation

How can i do that. I also want to make sure that query runs on member rather than client, so I don't want to use stream, values() etc.

Comment: you can find some examples in this repo: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/fast-aggregations

Comment: Here is the api https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#aggregate-com.hazelcast.aggregation.Aggregator-com.hazelcast.query.Predicate-